# Consulta promoção ecommerce

Tags: php, mysql, select, e-commerce

Estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma *ecommerce*, e me deparei com um problema para calcular o valor dos produtos, aplicando o desconto das promoções na consulta *SQL*, atualmente as regras de promoção estão sendo aplicadas no PHP, porém quando mando ordenar por valor, ele ordena sem levar em consideração o valor do produto com a promoção aplicada, e esse não é o objetivo, necessito que o produto que tiver a promoção na lista fique antes dos produtos de maior valor que ele.

*Obs.: As promoções podem ser associadas as categorias ou aos próprios produtos e um produto/categoria pode ter mais de uma promoção associada, as promoções podem acumular de acordo com uma flag existente dentro da tabela de promoção e os descontos podem ser preço fixo ou porcentagem de acordo com o campo tipo existente dentro da promoção, que determina se o desconto é porcentagem ou valor.*

Atualmente minha consulta retorna os produtos é assim *(de forma simplificada sem levar em consideração outros tabelas relacionadas que não inteferem em minha pergunta)*:

```
SELECT p.nome, MIN(e.valor) AS valor, p.id_produto, c.categoria
FROM produtos p 
INNER JOIN estoque e ON p.id_produto = e.id_produto
INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.id_categoria = c.id_categoria
GROUP BY p.id_produto
ORDER BY valor, p.id_produto
```

E minha tabela de promoção é assim:

```
id_promocao INT
data_inicial DATETIME
data_final DATETIME
acumular TINYINT(1)
ativo TINYINT(1)
tipo TINYINT(1)
valor DECIMAL(10,2)
```

E existe as tabelas *produtos_promocoes* que relaciona os produtos com as promoções e *categorias_promocoes* que relaciona as categorias com as promoções.

Alguém já fez algo parecido ou conhece alguma solução para isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido usando functions.

Links que auxiliaram:

[Procedures e functions](http://www.devmedia.com.br/stored-procedures-e-functions-no-mysql-com-phpmyadmin/30837)

[Cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html)